# store order id in other table on successful checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, magento

My boss asked me to store the `order id` and `timestamp` of the successful orders in a seperate table. And to achieve this I have to override magento's core things (either block, helper, model or controller). He had given me a reference of [this blog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part10-series-overriding). But I'm unable to figure out which block or controller I should override and how?

Till now I'd created a custom module which creates the specific table in which I have to add the entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all you want to do is to save the order_id and timestamp of newly place order.

Then you could create a custom module with an observer

1. To [create a new database](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) table in magento to store you order_id and timestamp
2. [Create an observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/197819/#t248190) for order place (eg `<sales_order_place_after>`)